# Pygame game loop trouble

Tags: python, import, while-loop, pygame

I am a novice programming a game in the Python language using Pygame. I'm having a problem with my game loop. I can only run my game once then I can't make my game loop again. I will post my code below here:

This is my mouse based menu (Menu.py)

```
import pygame, os, sys
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

def play_music(name, volume=0.7, loop=-1):
    fullname = os.path.join('data', name)
    try:
        pygame.mixer.music.load(fullname)
        pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(volume)
        pygame.mixer.music.play(loop)
    except:
        raise SystemExit, "Can't load: " + fullname

def load_sound(name, volume=0.05):
    fullname = os.path.join('data', name)
    try:
        sound = pygame.mixer.Sound(fullname)
        sound.set_volume(volume)
    except:
        raise SystemExit, "Can't load: " + fullname
    return sound

def run_game():
    import Grab

def reset_highscore():
    open("data/highscore.sav", "w").write(str(0))
    print "Grab High score reset to 0"

class GrabMenu():
    os.environ["SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED"] = "1"
    pygame.mouse.set_visible(0) #make the mouse cursor invisible
    pygame.display.set_caption("Grab") #name the game
    pygame.display.set_icon(pygame.image.load("data/Icon.png")) #set an icon for the game
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 800)) #screen resolution width and height
    background = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size()) #make the background
    background = pygame.image.load("data/BG.png").convert() #convert background 
    background = pygame.transform.scale(background,(800, 800)) #scale the background down to the screen resulution
    cursor = pygame.image.load("data/Hand1.png") #make a new cursor inside the game
    WHITE = (255, 255, 255) # colors
    YELLOW = (255, 216, 0)
    running = True # value for main loop
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    font = pygame.font.SysFont("times new roman", 28, bold=True) # menu font and text.
    fontcolor = WHITE
    fontcolor2 = WHITE
    fontcolor3 = WHITE
    fontcolor4 = WHITE
    mousetrigger = False
    mouseclick = load_sound("Click.wav", 3.5) # mouse click
    Menu1 = True
    Menu2 = False #options menu
    Menu3 = False #reset score menu
    #JOYSTICK
    try:
        j = pygame.joystick.Joystick(0) # create a joystick instance
        j.init() # init instance
        print 'Enabled joystick: ' + j.get_name()
    except:
        pass

    #main_loop
    while running == True:
        clock.tick(30)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                running = False, sys.exit()
            if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1: # if mouse button is pressed, (left mouse key only)
                if Menu1:
                    if ren_r.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()): # play the game
                        if Menu1 == False:
                            pass
                        else:
                            mouseclick.play()
                            run_game()
                    elif ren2_r.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()): #options
                        if Menu1 == False:
                            pass
                        else:
                            mouseclick.play()
                            Menu1 = False
                            Menu2 = True
                    elif ren3_r.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()): #how to play
                        if Menu1 == False:
                            pass
                        else:
                            mouseclick.play()
                    elif ren4_r.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()): #quit the game
                        if Menu1 == False:
                            pass
                        else:
                            mouseclick.play()
                            running = False, pygame.quit(), sys.exit()
                elif Menu2:
                    if ren5_r.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()): #reset high score
                        mouseclick.play()
                        reset_highscore()

                    elif ren6_r.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()): #go back
                        mouseclick.play()
                        Menu1 = True
                        Menu2 = False

        screen.blit(background, (0, 0)) #draw the background
        screen.blit(cursor, pygame.mouse.get_pos()) #set the cursor image as the new mouse cursor

        if Menu1:
            ren = font.render("Play", True, (fontcolor))
            ren_r = ren.get_rect()
            ren_r.x, ren_r.y = 340, 530

            ren2 = font.render("Options", True, (fontcolor2))
            ren2_r = ren2.get_rect()
            ren2_r.x, ren2_r.y = 340, 590

            ren3 = font.render("How to Play", True, (fontcolor3))
            ren3_r = ren3.get_rect()
            ren3_r.x, ren3_r.y = 340, 650

            ren4 = font.render("Quit Game", True, (fontcolor4))
            ren4_r = ren4.get_rect()
            ren4_r.x, ren4_r.y = 340, 710

            screen.blit(ren, (340, 530))
            screen.blit(ren2, (340, 590))
            screen.blit(ren3, (340, 650))
            screen.blit(ren4, (340, 710))

            if ren_r.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
                mousetrigger = True
                fontcolor = YELLOW
            else:
                fontcolor = WHITE

            if ren2_r.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
                mousetrigger = True
                fontcolor2 = YELLOW
            else:
                fontcolor2 = WHITE

            if ren3_r.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
                mousetrigger = True
                fontcolor3 = YELLOW
            else:
                fontcolor3 = WHITE

            if ren4_r.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
                mousetrigger = True
                fontcolor4 = YELLOW
            else:
                fontcolor4 = WHITE

        elif Menu2:
            options = font.render("Options", 1, (WHITE))

            ren5 = font.render("Reset High Score", True, (fontcolor))
            ren5_r = ren5.get_rect()
            ren5_r.x, ren5_r.y = 350, 650

            ren6 = font.render("Go back", True, (fontcolor2))
            ren6_r = ren6.get_rect()
            ren6_r.x, ren6_r.y = 350, 700

            screen.blit(options, (350, 600))
            screen.blit(ren5, (350, 650))
            screen.blit(ren6, (350, 700))

            if ren5_r.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
                mousetrigger = True
                fontcolor = YELLOW
            else:
                fontcolor = WHITE

            if ren6_r.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
                mousetrigger = True
                fontcolor2 = YELLOW
            else:
                fontcolor2 = WHITE

        pygame.display.update()
```

furthermore I use this when I press on "Play" text on my menu:

```
def run_game():
    import Grab
```

to start my main program "Grab.py":

```
import pygame, time, math, sys, random, os
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init() #make pygame ready
pygame.joystick.init

#my game code
done = False

while done == False:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True                   
        elif event.key == K_ESCAPE:
            if highscore == 0:
                pass
            if highscore < get_highscore():
                pass
            else:
                save_highscore(highscore)
            if score == 0:
                pass
            else:
                save_score(score)
            save_level(level)
            save_world(world)
            done = True 
            pygame.mixer.music.stop()
```

Main game loop ends here and sends me back to my menu just like I want. However, when I try to import grab again from my menu then nothing happens. I went and searched for "Python import cycle" from Google and I discovered a few things but i'm still stuck. There must be an easier way to make Grab.py loop from this:

```
def run_game():
    import Grab
```

Any help is very much appreciated.
Regards HJ.

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking, use `import` to load the definition of constants, functions or classes. Do not use it to run a bunch of statements. Call a function to run a bunch of statements.

For efficiency, Python only *imports modules once*. After it is loaded the first time, the module is cached in [`sys.modules`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/sys.html#sys.modules). Every time Python encounters an import statement it check if the module is in `sys.modules` and uses the cached module if it exists. Only if the module is not in `sys.modules` does Python execute the code in the module. Thus the code in the module is never executed more than once. That is why `import Grab` does not execute the code in `Grab.py` the second time the import statement is reached.

So, instead, refactor `Grab.py` to put all the code you wish to run multiple times inside a function:

```
import pygame, time, math, sys, random, os
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init() #make pygame ready
pygame.joystick.init()   # <-- Note you need parentheses to *call* the init function

def main():
    done = False

    while done == False:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                done = True                   
            elif event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                if highscore == 0:
                    pass
                if highscore < get_highscore():
                    pass
                else:
                    save_highscore(highscore)
                if score == 0:
                    pass
                else:
                    save_score(score)
                save_level(level)
                save_world(world)
                done = True 
                pygame.mixer.music.stop()
```

and then change

```
import Grab
```

to

```
import Grab    
Grab.main()
```

You could move `import Grab` to the top of Menu.py; generally speaking it is [recommended to put all the import statements at the top](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports) of any Python script or module.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I really appreciate your help, I got my game to run perfectly now. Thanks again!